# CPT UI and custom database table

Tags: plugin-development

I am new in wordpress dev.
I am building a plugin and I have a question
I have a custom table in the database 
Is there any way to create a Custom Post type connected to this table?
I am using CPT ui btw
How can I approach this problem? any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Once you have created the CPT, you can loop over the table to create custom post with this function : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: @mmm that would duplicate the data

Answer (score 0):

No, a custom post type is still a post in the posts table, you can't *connect* it because it's not a connection. It's a column in a table.

If you want to have the same UI as posts but for a custom table, you're going to have to implement it yourself:

- with a custom settings page
- custom SQL code
- A custom implementation of `WP_List_Table`, create a class that inherits from `WP_List_Table` and implement the methods so that it loads your database rows
- Another custom settings page that will act as the new/add/edit screen, implemented from scratch

Suffice to say this task is too broad to answer in a single question/answer, and you're facing a lot of manual recreation, including building pagination from scratch, etc

It would be easier to use a real custom post type, or to build a bespoke UI. My recommendation would be a JS powered UI using REST endpoints